# Android Tabs. Open new activity with every tab using layout include

Tags: android, android-intent, tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [set the tabbar bottom on android all activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120910/set-the-tabbar-bottom-on-android-all-activities)

I have an application with 3 tabs. Every tabs open one layout. I use the include option.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/tab1_ref"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    layout="@layout/tab1" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/tab2_ref"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    layout="@layout/tab2" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/tab3_ref"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    layout="@layout/tab3" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>


</LinearLayout>
```

And the main activity has the next code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         //Prueba con TABS
        Resources res = getResources();

        TabHost tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabs.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab1_ref);
        spec.setIndicator("Tab 1", null);
        tabs.addTab(spec);

       //Dont WORK the Intent 
       // Intent tab1Intent = new Intent(this, Tab1Activity.class);
       // spec.setContent(tab1Intent);


        spec=tabs.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab2_ref);
        spec.setIndicator("Tab 2", null);
        tabs.addTab(spec);

        spec=tabs.newTabSpec("Tab 3");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab3_ref);
        spec.setIndicator("Tab 3", null);
        tabs.addTab(spec);

        tabs.setCurrentTab(0);

        tabs.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Pulsada pestaña: " + tabId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        //Fin prueba tabs
    }
```

This work, when I push in different tabs I can see different layouts.

But, How Can open new activity when I activate new layout?
For example, If I push in tab2 open tab2activity.class.
I tried this and exception appears:

```
Intent tab1Intent = new Intent(this, Tab1Activity.class);
 spec.setContent(tab1Intent);
```

How Can open new activity when I activate new layout?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please write below code instead of your code for add multiple activities in one TabActivity, it will solve your problem.

ActivityStack.java

```
private Stack stack;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (stack == null)
        stack = new Stack<String>();
    // start default activity
    push("FirstStackActivity", new Intent(this, Tab_SampleActivity.class));
}

@Override
public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {
    pop();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    pop();
}

public void push(String id, Intent intent) {
    Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id, intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    if (window != null) {
        stack.push(id);
        setContentView(window.getDecorView());
    }
}

public void pop() {
    if (stack.size() == 1)
        finish();
    LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
    manager.destroyActivity(stack.pop(), true);
    if (stack.size() > 0) {
        Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(stack.peek()).getIntent();
        Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(stack.peek(), lastIntent);
        setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
    }
}
```

TabActivity.java

```
public class TabActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_screen);
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ActivityStack.class);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabId").setIndicator("Temp", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home));
        spec.setContent(intent);

        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, ActivityStack.class);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabId").setIndicator("Temp", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.invoice));
        spec1.setContent(intent1);
        tabHost.addTab(spec1);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

FirstActivity.java

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Tab Sample Activity ");
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getParent(), SecondActivity.class);
                ActivityStack activityStack = (ActivityStack) getParent();
                activityStack.push("SecondActivity", intent);
            }
        });
        setContentView(textView);
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("First Stack Activity ");
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getParent(), ThirdActivity.class);
                ActivityStack activityStack = (ActivityStack) getParent();
                activityStack.push("ThirdActivity", intent);
            }
        });
        setContentView(textView);
    }
}
```

ThirdActivity.java

```
public class ThirdActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Add Below XML files into your res/layout folder.

1) tab_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

2) main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.tabsample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".FirstActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TabActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityStack"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ThirdActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And see below link to my blog for more information on add multiple activities under one TabActivity with complete example.

[Android - Multiple Android Activities under one TabActivity](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2012/08/multiple-android-activities-in.html)

Comment: You might want to given an explanation and/or condensed code sample. Just pasting lots of code does not explain much...

Comment: ActivityStack extends to ActivityGroup.